# Recommended method for object typing under consideration of factory functions and serialization

Tags: javascript, types, symbols, duck-typing, dynamic-typing

I'm used to statically typed languages and may therefore see problems that actually do not exist in Javascript. Anyway, here are the methods of type checking of user-specific objects I'm familiar with:

- `instanceof`

Works as long as you use constructors. Since I prefer [factory functions](http://ericleads.com/2013/01/javascript-constructor-functions-vs-factory-functions/) and `Object.create`, `instanceof` is out of question.

- `isPrototypeOf`

Works with both constructor and factory functions, but is broken as soon as serialization comes into play (JSON or structured clone algorithm).

- Duck Typing

Works well with factory functions and serialization, but can lead to subtle errors and entails the risk of incompatibilities with external libraries/frameworks.

The thenable object (then-method) of the Promise/A+ spec is a good example. I consider that harmful.

- Pseudo symbols

transducer.js (and more and more other) use this pseudo symbols like `@@transducer/step` to prevent naming conflicts and thus give their objects a notion of type. It's merely a variant of duck typing, but meets my requirements.

- `toString`

I tend to use the toString method for type checking, since it is already used for native type checks via `Object.prototype.toString`. Usually `toString` returns the string representation of an object. I extend this behavior by letting toString return a type identifier if the method is called with an argument. The following example is highly simplified:

```
var proto = {}, o;

proto.toString: function (_) { return _ === undefined ? JSON.stringify(this) : "someType"};
o = Object.create(proto);
o.a = 123, o.b = "abc", o.c = true;

o.toString(); // {"a":123,"b":"abc","c":true}
o.toString(true); // someType
```

Since toString is mainly used for logging this should work out. However, `toString` gets lost during serialization.

Are there any other methods?

Is there a best practice that can be recommended?

**Update:** I need type checking specifically for ad hoc polymorphism aka function/method overloading and in the context of working with web workers.  [Raganwald](http://raganwald.com/2014/06/15/immutable-structs.html) uses the terms structural and semantic typing in his blog post, which in my opinion fit very well on the subject.

Comment: You can also use typeof() function. Not sure if it would solve your serilization problem but worth giving it a try

Comment: @sinanspd: `typeof` is an operator not a function. This distinction is important, because operators are not first class in javascript and hence can't be treated like normal data. Moreover `typeof` is not suitable for distinguishing user-specific objects, but for native types like `string`, `number` or `object`.

Comment: my bad should have read the question better :)

Comment: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/ this is a pretty thorough examination of the topic

Comment: What for do you need to check the types of your objects exactly?

Comment: If you expect JSON-parsed objects (which will neither have a custom prototype nor methods) to "type check", then you're left with duck typing. There's nothing else.

Comment: @Bergi: For a point free map function that can handle various GADTs for instance. multimthods in general. Stuff like this.

Comment: @Bergi: I guess there is no best practice. Each method has its merits and should be used in respective situations appropriately. I am preparing an answer right now but still need some time.

Comment: @Bergi: Serialization requires prepared objects (flattened prototype chain, no funcs, no symbols, ...), I've got this. I'll use toJSON/fromJSON or similar

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: For a general-purpose `map` function I can only recommend [duck typing with a symbol](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/issues/92). Have you seen the fantasy-land spec and Ramda, btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a weakly `+"123" === 123 // true` and dynamically typed `var obj = {}, obj = 123; // 123` language with a prototype system.

The question is how useful it is in such a language to distinguish objects at runtime by the constructors which have instantiated them. Actually constructors are merely ordinary functions in Javascript and no matter what you do, you always compare the identity of prototypes:

```
function Ctor() {}
var o = new Ctor();
var p = Object.create(o);

o instanceof Ctor === Ctor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o) === true;
o.isPrototypeOf(p) === true;
```

So why use constructors at all? Prototypes are also just ordinary objects and thus factory functions are a logical consequence of the described inheritance and object model.

Object distinction should be based on a technique corresponding to the nature of the used language. As I said, Javascript is dynamically typed and therefore ideally suited for duck typing:

```
var o = {empty: function () { return this.keys().length === 0; }}

if (empty in o) {
  "empty interface implemented";
}
```

Since keys in objects are merely string based, name collisions in connection with duck typing were inevitable. Fortunately symbols have found their way in Javascript since ES2015.

Symbols have an identity and thus can be shared without ever colliding with each other:

```
Symbol("foo") === Symbol("foo"); // false
```

Although they have identity, symbols are among the primitive types in Javascript, are immutable like strings and can be used as object keys. Duck typing with symbols evolves from a mere hash table lookup to the comparison of identities. Thus, symbols can make a reliable statement whether a certain object has implemented a certain interface:

```
var o = {};
var empty = Symbol("empty");

o[empty] = function () { return Object.keys(this).length === 0; }
```

Whenever an object has the `empty` property we can be sure, it has implemented the right interface. Better yet, we can mix in various other interfaces (which use symbols as keys), look up the existence of every single of them (by their identity) and all this without name collisions or growing prototype chains.

With that things like ad hoc polymorphism (aka function overloading) can be realized with ease.

A final sentence to serialization: Serialization means to lose almost everything: Object identities, prototype chains, functions, symbols, etc.

So whenever you use a web worker or a messaging system that doesn't share memory, you have to prepare your complex objects for serialization and restore them afterwards, such as with [folktale](https://github.com/folktale/encoding.json) for instance.

Comment: If you're using ES6, you actually don't even need a constructor to support `instanceof`. Check out `Symbol.hasInstance` :-)

Comment: Can transpiler handle `Symbol.hasInstance`?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I can say if it is a "best" practice, but if you have access to es6 you can use a Symbol property to specify an object type.

```
const Type = Symbol('Type');

const ExampleFactory = function(a, b, c) {

    return {
      a,
      b,
      c,
      [Type]: 'ExampleFactory'
    };
};
```

Symbols are unique, non-string primitives (though you can specify a string description).  You can't accidentally grab the [Type] property by iteration, and you can perform a simple check with

```
 obj[Type] === 'ExampleFactory;
```

Comment: You were right, symbols are the right tool to distinguish objects but since symbols have identity, you don't need a special "type symbol"